# Posing a URL with IP is blank

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3.5.17 and I'm trying to pass a URL with an IP from one of my forms and it's always being removed when I get to the controller.

If I post `http://10.3.37` I receive

```
Array
(
    [asset_field_id] => 3
    [value] => http://10.3.37
    [asset_id] => 13
)
```

as expected. But if I put in the full address `http://10.3.37.1` I receive

```
Array
(
)
```

If I change the IP to a domain name, or remove the 'h' or modify the string in any other way I get the result I'd expect. Is there some setting or security thing I'm not aware of?

Somewhere along the line all of the form data is being stripped out and I don't know where.

This form isn't using any kind of validation that I'm aware of.

Comment: Is this ajax related?

Comment: Not using ajax for this request.

Comment: Can see what is sent in browser dev tools network. Not sure if that helps or not

Comment: Hmmm. Normal requests that go through give a 200, but the IP request gives a 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem was ModSecurity. I loosened that up and thing started working as expected.